# cronjob can't find file on EC2

Tags: unix, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I have a script, called `script.py` that is on an EC2 instance. The script reads a file in the same folder (code: `open(data.csv, 'r')`) called `data.csv`. Here is the cron job:

```
* * * * * /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/python /home/ubuntu/project/script.py > /var/log/myjob.log 2&>1
```

When I run the script myself `python script.py` is works perfectly. However, when cron runs the script, a python error is printed (as I intended) in the `myjob.log` file:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'data.csv'
```

I suspect cronjob doesn't run the script in the same directory as when I run it myself, however, I do not know how to write the crontab line to tell cron to run the script from the directory that the script is in.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `/home/ubuntu`...

```
* * * * * cd /home/ubuntu/ && ./anaconda3/bin/python ./project/script.py > /var/log/myjob.log 2>&1
```

Adding `2>&1` to the end is unrelated to your question, but captures the `STDERR` output into your log, which you probably also want.